# Evento de clique em um TextField conflita como JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

Estou aprendendo a criar um sistema de vendas e criei esse método para pegar informações de um TextField e jogar dentro de uma tabela através do clique do botão enter. Criei um try-catch para tratar exceções e, se entrar no catch, abre uma JOptionPane. Quando aperto enter novamente, o botão “OK” do `JOptionPane` é apertado por padrão.

Porém, quando clico no enter para fechar o `JOptionPane`, ele fecha e abre de novo, pois é como se o evento de clique do TextField fosse ativado, e acaba ficando um espécie de loop, onde toda vez que aparece o `JOptionPane` e o enter é apertado, ele some e aparece de novo.

Como resolver isso?

```
private void pegarConteudo(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
    jLabelStatus.setText("Caixa Aberto");
    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    if (e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {//Verifica se a tecla ENTER foi pressionada 
        try {
            modelProdutos = controllerProdutos.retornarProdutosController(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldPesquisa.getText()));
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
                modelo.getRowCount() + 1,
                modelProdutos.getIdProduto(),
                modelProdutos.getProdutoNome(),
                quantidade,
                modelProdutos.getProdutoValor(),
                modelProdutos.getProdutoValor() * quantidade
            });
            jTextFieldValorTotal.setText(somaValorTotal() + "");
            jTextFieldPesquisa.setText("");
            quantidade = 1;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Produto não cadastrado", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            jTextFieldPesquisa.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e apresente um **[mcve]** p para que seja possivel executar o codigo.

Answer (score 4):

Apesar de você não ter fornecido um trecho em que fosse possível reproduzir(*fica a dica para próximas perguntas, sempre forneça um [**exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*), testei algumas prováveis hipóteses que podem ocasionar isso e acabei por achar uma situação que simula perfeitamente o problema da pergunta:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyEventTexFieldJOptionPaneTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(KeyEventTexFieldJOptionPaneTest::new);
    }

    private Component getInstance() {
        return this;
    }

    public KeyEventTexFieldJOptionPaneTest() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 300));
        contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        textField = new JTextField(10);
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    System.out.println("enter pressionado e liberado");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getInstance(), "teste");
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(textField);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

A causa aqui é justamente o método utilizado para capturar o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, pois o `keyReleased()` é disparado quando alguma tecla é liberada do pressionamento. Se você executar o código, verá que, quando pressionar o ENTER no campo de texto, o modal abrirá, e se apertar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> novamente, como o foco está no botao <kbd>OK</kbd>, está ação pressionará este botão e o `JOptionPane` será fechado mas o evento será disparado no campo de texto novamente logo após o fechamento, fazendo com que seja reaberto, e se continuar apertando o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, isso continuará ocorrendo num loop.

A demonstração abaixo deixa a explicação mais clara:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

---

## Como resolver então?

A forma mais simples de se resolver sem alterar demais ou adicionar quaisquer complexidades no código acima é alterar o método para `keyPressed()`, que é disparado imediatamente assim que a tecla é pressionada. Mas como o modal do `JOptionPane` interrompe a execução do restante da tela enquanto está sendo exibido, e somente é fechado até que o botão *OK* seja liberado do pressionamento(ou seja, até ocorrer o `keyReleased()` nele), quando você pressionar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> novamente, não será capturado pelo campo de texto.

Veja o teste abaixo com a alteração:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>